# std::unique_lock::_Owns data member is not atomic?

Tags: c++

Looking through the std::unique_lock implementation in MSVC14, I noticed it has a data member

`bool _Owns;`

Since _Owns is used by operator=, operator() and owns_lock() amongst other, I was expecting _Owns to be atomic. Anyone can comment as to why it is not?

Thanks.

Comment: IIRC, at least on x86 systems, all bool operation are naturally atomic.  Implementations are allowed to take advantage of the hardware they are being compiled on to produces the best performing code they can.

Comment: It could also be there is synchronization is those functions you've mentioned.  Did you check them to see if there is or isn't?

Comment: `std::unique_lock` is not intended to be shared by multiple threads.  It is not a mutex, it represents an active lock on a mutex. Only the owning thread should ever access it, so there is no need to synchronization.

Comment: While it may be interesting to read a standard library implementation's code, nothing you find there can be assumed to be correct for use at the user level. Standard library implementations are allowed to do things that is normally not allowed, usually having to do with targeting a specific platform and a specific compiler version, whose unique non-portal quirks can be exploited.

Comment: Thanks all. Missed completely this is not supposed to be thread-shared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `std::unique_lock` object cannot be accessed by multiple threads (that would be completely counter to its purpose), so it doesn't need to consider atomicity of the data stored in itself.

The lock object has a reference to a mutex object (e.g. `std::mutex`) on which it calls member functions to lock or unlock the mutex for the thread owning the lock object. That mutex object is what is shared between threads.